# Commenting out comments

Tags: c++, comments

I've noticed, using visual studio 2003, that I can "comment out" my comments to make them no longer be comments. This one needs an example:

If I have:

```
/*
int commented_out = 0;
*/
```

I can comment out the /* and */ with // and code within the /* and */ is no longer "commented out" (the text changes to non-comment color **and** the compiler treats it as code once again). Like so:

```
///*
int commented_out = 0;
//*/
```

I've found this is true for msvc 2003, is this normal C++ behavior or is it just a fluke that works with this compiler?

Comment: If you comment out the comments, what else would you expect?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yep, this is perfectly normal behavior.  The C++ standard says that a `/*` is the start of a comment block only if it itself is not commented out.  I often use what you've written above to comment or uncomment a block of code by adding/deleting one character.  A nice little trick for switching between two blocks of code, one of which is always commented out is:

```
//*
code block 1 (uncommented)
/*/
code block 2 (commented)
//*/
```

Now, delete one slash from the start, and it becomes

```
/*
code block 1 (commented)
/*/
code block 2 (uncommented)
//*/
```

Not something to use in production code, but very useful for quick debugging changes.

Comment: Hadn't thought of that before. That's great.

Answer (score 10):

It should work in any compiler as the `//` is encountered first in the input stream.

I tend to use `#if 0` for this sort of stuff and change it to `#if 1` to uncomment, shown here:

```
#if 0
    int commented_out = 0;
#endif
```

Then I don't have to worry about comment markers at all.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this works in almost any language with C style block comments.

```
/*
int foo = 0;
/*/
int foo = 1;
//*/
```

or even XML comments

```
<!--->
a
<!-->
b
<!---->
```

unfortunately I'm drawing a blank on lua's lightsaber comments

```
--[[---------
---------]]--
```